# Secured Web API with azure return a sign-in page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-3.1

I built a web API with .net core 3.1 and I secured it with Azure Active Directory.
When I try to connect to it from Postman using an access token, I get a sign-in html as a response. I generated the token from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer or by connecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token in both cases I got the same result

my Azure setting in appsetting.json file

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "my-client-id",
    "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "my-Tenant-id"
 }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);

       services.AddTransient(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));
   }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

My contoller

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       return Ok("value");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you get access token? Is that you project your own API vai  Azure AD then you cannot call the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) on how you can make this flow work. Have you created a scope as mentioned in Step 2> step 6 and used it while hitting the token endpoint? I am not sure how you can get a valid token for this scenario from MS graph explorer as this is your own API. Use the azure ad's [token endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) to get valid tokens. Hope this helps. Please mark this as verified if this solves your problem.

Comment: the sample you provided had the answer, thanks